# Oracle tables show "not_found?.TABLENAME

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle. A legacy script created our table structure.

When I try to select from, say, tableA, sql developer very helpfully finds the table as I type. But instead of filling in a valid user it shows me (eg)

```
SELECT * FROM not_found?.tableA
```

I'm guessing the script pulled the user incorrectly, but the table seems to actually exist (or it wouldn't fill in the user, n'est ce pas?). Does anyone know WHERE THE HECK IT IS?

Comment: what version of sql developer are you using? and please update your question with a screenshot showing the suggestion as you type and then another as it comes out - then I can help you and possible id a bug/solution

Comment: Are table or schema names created case-sensitive? That tends to be a quick way to confuse tools that aren't expecting anything weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to find the schema in which the table is:

```
select owner from all_tables where table_name = 'TABLEA';
```

Comment: This gave me the prefix ~ yay! But if I start to type SELECT * FROM myuser.TA it does not complete table names. And some are pretty hefty. :) Any further thoughts?

Comment: Autocomplete is a feature that depends on the intelligence of the tool. Apparently, your tool is not clever enough to cover your needs. Consider updating to the latest version of sqldeveloper, unless you already use the very latest one.